# how to parse data from websocket with python?

Tags: python, websocket

I want some data that send by websocket.
and I can use python something like urllib
How can I do this?
sorry about my poor english and thanks for read my question

Answer (score -1):

If it is just about parsing the data, it depends upon the format of the data. If you are receiving JSON as a response, you can do json.loads() and treat the retrieved value as a python dictionary.

If you are looking at some python libraries/examples of dealing with websockets, take a look at:
https://github.com/makaimc/python-websockets-example